# Loop through directory, pause for user changes, echo name of new directory in batch file

Tags: batch-file

I'm using the below. I've used FC and COMP to look at files generated  by DIR. No not real sure how to approach this issue.

Basically I need to pause the script, another program will create a new folder, once the user presses enter, it should show the name of the new folder.

```
 (for /d %%i in ("%~dp0") do (

 pause>nul|set/p =Add folder..

 if exist "%~dp0%%~nxi" echo(%%~i)

 )

 cmd /k
```

Comment: @Gerhard no, I know a loop wont work the way I'm using it. I need to take an account of the directories, let the user add a new one through a different system, then echo the name of the new folder

Comment: I do not want to make a new directory with cmd/.bat this must be done by another system based on user in puts. I want to create a list / inventory of the directors, pause so the user can input the info on the other system,  then echo the name of the new directory

Comment: The standard use of pause is fine. The user will un pause when they have finished the task

Comment: A list will work, it it can be avoided that's fine.

Comment: See answer below, it should help you get to what you want to achieve.

Comment: I need to echo the name of the new directory

Comment: I know, did you see the answer below??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To list the number of directories in the current path:

This should point you in the right direction, you can run it as is for now to see.

```
@echo off
:start
echo Press Enter when you want to see the new Foldername:
pause >nul
cls
for /f %%i in ('dir /b /ad /o-d') do set "newfolder=%%i" & goto reveal
:reveal
echo New Folder is "%newfolder%"
goto start
```

All this does is to sort by the latest modified date of all folders and only echo the latest. Simple as that.

You can also add a counter that will show you the number of folders:

```
@echo off
:start
echo Press Enter when you want to see the new Foldername:
pause >nul
cls
for /f %%a in ('dir ^| findstr /i "Dir(s)"') do set count=%%a
for /f %%i in ('dir /b /ad /o-d') do set "newfolder=%%i" & goto reveal
:reveal
echo Number of folders: %count%
echo Latest Folder:     "%newfolder%"
goto start
```

Or if you want to see the Full path of the folder, not just the new name of it, use `%%~fi`:

```
@echo off
:start
echo Press Enter when you want to see the new Foldername:
pause >nul
cls
for /f %%a in ('dir ^| findstr /i "Dir(s)"') do set count=%%a
for /f %%i in ('dir /b /ad /o-d') do set "newfolder=%%~fi" & goto reveal
:reveal
echo Number of folders: %count%
echo Latest Folder:     "%newfolder%"
goto start
```

And here is a version that does not require any user input, it will detect the new folder for you.

```
@echo off
set newfold=
set oldfold=
:start
for /f %%i in ('dir /b /ad /o-d') do set "newfold=%%i" & goto reveal
:reveal
if not defined oldfold set "oldfold=%newfold%"
if not "%newfold%"=="%oldfold%" (
    echo New Folder detected: %newfold%
    set oldfold=%newfold%
)
timeout /t 3 /nobreak >nul
goto start
```

Comment: language independent method to count the folders: `for /f %%a in ('dir /b /ad ^|find /c /v ""') do set count=%%a`

Comment: see edit for a last option, does not require user input as it will detect the directory.